# New to Angular - Write a log file

Tags: angular, typescript, logging

I don't have any background with angular or typescript. I'm a Data Scientist but currently we have to write a code in typescript that writes something into a file everytime a function is called.
I followed the Tour of Heroes tutorial just for testing (https://angular.io/tutorial) and then I tried to create this:

```
var fName = arguments.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1];

var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = 'Last Sync: ' + currentdate.getDate() + '/'
    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + '/'
    + currentdate.getFullYear() + ' @ '
    + currentdate.getHours() + ':'
    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ':'
    + currentdate.getSeconds() + ':'
    + currentdate.getMilliseconds();

const fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('logs.txt', 'C1 F0 ' + datetime, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

But this gives me an error saying **Can't resolve 'fs'**

I've already seen that it's normal because it's a client-side framework. So any workarounds or any solutions?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I said something wrong.

Comment: If you want to write a file you have to do this from `node`, not within the browser (with angular or other framework).

Comment: `fs` is a NodeJS (server-side Javascript) library, Where do you want to write your file ? You might have to use something other than TS and angular

Comment: @maxime1992 what do you mean with doing this from the node?

Comment: @Nicolas basically we want to write a local file with information everytime the function is called

Comment: @ShabbirMomin Only server-side code can write a file on the server.  You cannot do this from your browser.

Comment: @ShabbirMomin Then you don't have much choice. You could make yourself a basic web API that could write to a file, since it's serverside. Your frontend would then call this API when it need to write to a file.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will see with the team a solution that is within our area of expertise.

Comment: You need more than just Angular for this. As others have said, you can't write to the file system from the browser. If you're trying to make a (desktop) app, you should look into Electron, and if you like Angular (i know you said you're new to it), you should look into angular-electron. Electron is used to create cross platform desktop apps using web tech.

Comment: I was talking about NodeJS https://nodejs.org/en